# Break table <td> in two lines

Tags: css, html-table

How to break the table td in two lines using media query?

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/eydg96zj/)**

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
        .table > tbody > tr > td {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean one `td` below the other one? Or break the text inside the `td`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block;` to occupy the full width.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  @include font-size(1.4);
  .table > tbody > tr > td {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Date posted</td>
      <td>01/06/2015</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to set them to `display: block;`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eydg96zj/3/)